# MySQL Workbench se cierra inesperadamente despues de iniciar

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, opensuse

Installe **MySQL Workbench 6.3.10 en openSUSE LEAP 15**. Cuando quiero abrir esta aplicacion intenta iniciar pero se cierra inmediatamente y este mensaje aparece despues de ejecutar en "Konsole".

```
sudo mysql-workbench
```

> Found /usr/lib64/libprojectM-qt5.so.2
>   /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib64/mysql-workbench/libwbpublic.so.6.3.10: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN18OGRGeometryFactory13createFromWkbEPhP19OGRSpatialReferencePP11OGRGeometryi13OGRwkbVariant

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta estas en **SO en español**

Comment: listo, gracias por la observacion.